# Удалить данные из Firebase? (React)

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Подскажите, не получается удалить данные из Firebase.
Избитая схема, - есть список с названиями фирм. В каждой строке списка есть триггер для удаления этой строки.

Структура код Функции и db в Firebase:

```js
const handlerActiveDelete = () => {
  const activeKey = push(child(ref(db), 'ListCompany')).key;
  return remove(ref(db), ['/ListCompany/' + activeKey]);
}
```

```html
<pre>
'ListCompany': 
- N-fdsfsdw5345
--- id: dsfdsf
--- name: 'AAA' 
--- email: aaa@gmail.com 

- N-fdsfsdw534ert 
--- id: dsf6546 
--- name: 'BBB' 
--- email: 
bbb@gmail.com 

... ...
</pre>
```

При таком коде функции удаляет весь список, а мне нужно чтобы только данную строку. Почему так происходит?
[Документация](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web-version-9_5)
Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

> вызвать remove() **для ссылки на расположение этих данных**.

Ваш вызов

> `remove(ref(db), ['/ListCompany/' + activeKey])`

Вы в `remove` передаете 2 аргумента `ref(db)` и `['/ListCompany/' + activeKey]` (ссылка на базу и массив с одним строчным элементом).

Если верить документации, то правильно так `remove(ref(db, 'ListCompany/' + activeKey))`

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, но firebase думает видимо по другому. Проверил еще раз: return remove(ref(db, 'ListCompany/' + activeKey)); // Ничего не происходит //, a 
return remove(ref(db), 'ListCompany/' + activeKey); // Удаляется вся database //

Comment: @Cobra777 Я правильно понимаю, что у вас есть коллекция документов, в которой 1 компания - это 1 документ. А в свою очередь activeKey - это id документа компании. Правильно?

Comment: @Cobra777 посмотрел типизацию `remove`, он принимает 1 аргумент - ref на документ, который необходимо удалить (должно быть именно `remove(ref(db, 'ListCompany/' + activeKey))`. Проверяйте, правильно ли у вас формируется ссылка на документ

Comment: Да @xydope, есть список с названием ListCompany, в котором есть 10 компаний. В каждой компании есть 4 пункта и всё. activeKey - это скорее динамический ключ, который присваивает firebase конкретному элементу (в моем случаи Компании) при его создании. Ок, спасибо за мысли, буду пробывать/читать/изучать дальше.